# Regex Javascript block Input

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

i've just build a javascript function with a regex control that allows 3 numbers and one dot.

```js
function restrictNumber(e) {
  var newValue = this.value.replace(new RegExp(/^(?!^(?:\d{1,3}|\d(?:\d?\.\d?|\.\d{2}))$).*/, 'gm'), "");
  this.value = newValue;
}

$('.decimal').on('input', restrictNumber);
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<input class="decimal" type="text">
```

The specs of the regex are:

- max. 3 numbers
- only one or no dot
- dot can be anywhere

Here is a regex demo for it: https://regex101.com/r/3Ru1O3/3/

i tried to "block" the input when a char is put in that isn't fitting. But when i try to test it deletes my hole string.

How can i change that behaviour that i just can't set new numbers put the string isnt vanishing.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say much about your actual requirements, as in, if the decimal is required at a certain place value, etc.. but based on what your existing regex does, it could definitely be shortened.

```js
function restrictNumber(e) {
  var newValue = this.value.replace(/[^\d\.]/, "").substr(0,4);
  this.value = newValue;
}

$('.decimal').on('input', restrictNumber);
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<input class="decimal" type="text">
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer, but the problem is that people should not add more than 3 numbers.

Comment: @lvollmer - Ok, and what about the decimal place? is it required? Does it have to be at a certain position? Instead of making me redo my answer a bunch of times why don't you provide the **entire spec** in the question.

Comment: @i wrestled a bear once. Yes, sorry i updated the question.